# Replace Dimmer Switch with normal switch

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle, dimmer-switch

I had a dimmer switch setup in my dining room.  The dimmer switch stopped working and I want to replace it with a normal switch (3 screws which are hot, neutral, ground).

In the picture below, there seems to be a lot more going on than I had anticipated.

I tried connecting the "line"(tested hot) wire and "Neutral" wire and the "Ground" wire to the normal switch but it didn't work and then I'm not sure what to do with the "Load" wire.

[image]

[image: Outlet Setup]

Comment: The light switch is not actually in a three-way wiring? As in, two switches control one light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only wires that should be connected to the new switch are line, load and ground. The old switch likely had circuitry that required a neutral for operation. Basic switches do not use a neutral, just line, load and ground.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct response!  I did that and it worked!